# Change li class via js to become links

Tags: javascript, css, dom, hyperlink

How do I create links based on the lists below and change them from being lists to links by Javascript.

```
<li class="navigation">LOVE</li>
<li class="navigation">HATE</li>
<li class="navigation">LIFE</li>
```

should become:

```
<li class="navigation><a href="#LOVE">LOVE</a></li>
...
```

Comment: Links to what? You need to be more specific.

Comment: How did you end up in a situation where you needed to do this? Also, where did you get stuck? Finding the LI elements? Looping over them? finding their content? Creating replacement content?

Answer (score 2):

Without jQuery:

```js
function makeLinks(ul) {
  for (i of document.querySelectorAll(ul + " > li")) {
    var t = i.innerHTML;
    i.innerHTML = "<a href='" + t.toLowerCase() + "'>" + t + "</a>";
  }
}

makeLinks("#menu");
```

```html
<ul id="menu">
  <li class="navigation">LOVE</li>
  <li class="navigation">HATE</li>
  <li class="navigation">LIFE</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

As I don't see any jQuery tag, here is a solution using plain javascript.

To loop over all `li` using `querySelectorAll()` and replace each `textContent` with desired nodes:

```js
liAll = document.querySelectorAll('li');
liAll.forEach(function(elt) {
  txt = elt.textContent;
  link = document.createElement('a');
  atxt = document.createTextNode(txt);
  link.appendChild(atxt);
  link.setAttribute('href', '#' + txt);
  elt.appendChild(link);
  elt.firstChild.remove();
});
```

```html
<li class="navigation">LOVE</li>
<li class="navigation">HATE</li>
<li class="navigation">LIFE</li>
```

Comment: Why would you not use `replaceChild`?

Comment: @torazaburo I'm not sure I can use `replaceChild()` with a string.

Answer (score -1):

```
$('li.navigation').each(function(index,element){
  var me = $(this);
  $(element).replace(function(){
     return "<a href='your reference here'>"+me.text+"</a>"
  })
})
```